# Cannot read data from Azure Mongo after copying from Storage Gen2 using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Source: Azure Storage Gen 2 (file with 10 json lines)
Sink: Azure Cosmos with Mongo API

I used Azure Data factory pipeline (Copy activity) to move the file data to Mongo collection. Copy is successful but when I run find({}) on my collection, it returns 0 records. When I run stats(), it shows the count as 10 which is expected. I cannot figure out what is the issue when reading these records from Robo3T to query Mongo DB.

I created second pipeline to read data from Mongo and write to Azure Storage to test if the data really is present in Mongo. I was able to write all 10 records to storage. It proves the data is present in Mongo, but I cannot read/access it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're running `find()`. You haven't included any detail, so it's difficult to know what your specific issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to directly read data collection stored in the data or any databases. Must you use Mongo Shell via Azure Portal. Where you have to go to your Azure  Cosmos DB resource -> Data Explorer -> Mongo Shell. If there any specific errors here is the [troubleshooting document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-troubleshoot).